# Alternatives to trap doors as fences (doesn't work anymore)

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[Trap doors no longer keep animals in.](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-150117) Therefore, I'm wondering if there are any good alternatives, except for fences with carpets on top.

What's the best way to fence in animals, while allowing the user to jump in and out?

Gates in fences are quite annoying if I have many animals in a small enclosure, as they tend to escape and/or get in the way of closing the gate.

I'm using Bedrock 1.19, if that matters.